# Segregating/Separating a device (ATT 3G Microcell) from internal network without using DMZ

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, tomato, vlan

I would like to put the [ATT 3G Microcell](http://www.att.com/standalone/3gmicrocell/?fbid=fxxQxyC4bq-) in an isolated network from a network that has the rest of my devices, by which I mean I want the ATT 3G Microcell to only be able to access the Internet, but not "see" or access my internal network.  I understand the options for configuring this on my Asus RT-AC66U running <strike>Tomato (Shibby Version: 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-1.23.16 K26AC USB AIO-64K)</strike> Asuswrt-Merlin - build 376.48 (xx-xxx-2014) [NOTE 1] are using:

1. VLAN
2. Routing (iptables) tables

My understanding is that to use VLAN, I have to "create" a different physical segment, which means I have to give up one of the LAN ports on my router to assign to the VLAN.  Undesirable because of the way I have my network set-up, which is that the Microcell is connected to a switch to which other devices that do need to be on the internal network are connected, and that switch is connected to my router (LAN port 1), which sits in a completely different part of the house, where LAN ports 2-4 are used to connect a server with multiple Ethernet adapters.

Am I miss understanding how VLAN works?

If not, is there a way to do this by using routing tables?  Firewall rules?

FWIW, these are the only ports that ATT Microcell uses:

TCP/UDP Ports [ NOTE:  All ports listed need to be configured for inbound and outbound connections.]

- 123/UDP: NTP timing (NTP traffic)
- 443/TCP: Https over TLS/SSL for provisioning and management traffic
- 4500/UDP: IPSec NAT Traversal (for all signaling, data, voice traffic)
- 500/UDP: IPSec Phase 1 prior to NAT detection (after NAT detection, 4500/UDP is used)
- 4500/UDP: After NAT detection, 4500/UDP is used

Note:
1.  I may be buying a managed switch with VLAN capability, so any opinions would be welcomed.